# How to resolve charset utf8 in PHP?

Tags: php

I use function `htmlspecialchars()` in PHP and cyrillic symbols.

I get error:

> Message: htmlspecialchars(): charset `utf8' not supported, assuming
>   utf-8

Is there alretnative `htmlspecialchars()` or solution for this charset?

**PHP code:**

```
$text  = htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES,$charset);
```

Comment: so set `utf-8` as the default encoding, instead of `utf8`...

Comment: Should be UTF-8 .. check this http://w3schools.invisionzone.com/index.php?showtopic=34925

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember to call `filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);` first if you bring the data from a REQUEST to this arena. This is what you need in order to use htmlspecialchars:

```
$text = htmlspecialchars($name, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```